# php ajax generating csrf token

Tags: php, ajax, csrf-protection

I am using multiple ajax (post) requests on a page in php. These resquests are not entering anything into database, only getting data. One of these requests is hitting the database in every 4-5 seconds. So, i am thinking to use csrf so that to protect from public requests from other domain's.

- Is Csrf is the solution in this scenario ?
- If yes, then should i generate one single token for all ajax requests.
- Should i refresh token after completion of each request. I am asking this because i have tried to use csrf-magic but it is not updating token after ajax request (i.e using same token again and again for ajax until page is refreshed).

Anything else security or performance advice in this scenario (hitting the database in every 4-5 second by ajax request) ?

Comment: Why are you getting data every 4-5 seconds?

Comment: actually it is a display board like airport display.

Comment: so update the board only when the data is updated

Comment: but i have to send ajax to check database if data is updated

Comment: Read about web sockets, or try to find out ways with which you will do an ajax request only when data is updated, you can even try Pusher